# Java Timers and TextFields

Tags: java, timer, textfield

I have a panel where I have an uneditable Textfield. I want to be able to add a `textField.setText(timer);` sort of thing in the panel. I basically just want the JTextArea to display it like this: 0:0:0.

I've tried making Timers, TimerTasks, ActionListeners and the sort. I can't get the hang of this. Maybe it's because where I'm adding the timer? At the moment I tried adding it in a `public void guiComponents() throws Exception{...}`. This method holds all the properties for the panel, the frame it's in and other components.

Maybe I'm not understating the whole concept of timers. Origanlly I tried using a double-nested for loop to achieve this task, but because this has to go on while the rest of the program is running, I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a JTextField for this. Use a JLabel to display text. Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TimerTime extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel timeLabel;

    public TimerTime()
    {
        timeLabel = new JLabel( new Date().toString() );
        getContentPane().add(timeLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        timeLabel.setText( new Date().toString() );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TimerTime frame = new TimerTime();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        int time = 1000;
        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(time, frame);
        timer.setInitialDelay(1);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what `Date` does. But I don't want real time. More like counting upwards after the app has started to run, and it will continue to increment till the end.

Comment: @SelfDeceit That concept is the same.  In the `actionPerformed` method, you need to increment the counter and format the output. I'm sure your capable of at least that much